# DES Decoding in C# WP 8.1

Tags: c#, cryptography, windows-phone-8.1, des

The System.Security.Cryptography does include a DES Decode method, but the Windows.Security.Cryptography Namespace for Windows Phone 8.1 programming doesn't include any method for decoding DES.

I just found a Class, `Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.SymmetricAlgorithmNames.DesCbc`,
but I don't have any idea how to decrypt my DES encrypted String. I would appreciate every idea you have in your mind.

I think I've got it.
Code Snippet:

```
strAsymmetricAlgName = SymmetricAlgorithmNames.DesCbc;
SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider objAlgProv = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(strAsymmetricAlgName);

CryptographicKey keyPair = objAlgProv.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary("xxx", BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8));

IBuffer val = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(keyPair, CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(encodedData, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8), null);

byte[] arr = val.ToArray();

string returnValue = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arr, 0, arr.Length);
```

I currently don't know the  initialization vector that's why it is `null`.
I am still not 100 % sure if that is right.
The DES string is encrypted by a Java programm:

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance( "DES" );
Key k = new SecretKeySpec( pass.getBytes(), "DES" );
c.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k );

OutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream( out, c );
cos.write( bytes );
cos.close()
```

I can't find any Information about the initialization vector.

Comment: Why DES? A 56 bit key is not secure.

Comment: Ye i know that, but still better than no encryption. The Use Case doesn't really need a higher encryption and the DES encryption is already built in a long time ago.

Comment: DES is barely better than nothing. DES keys could already be cracked in 24 hours 15 years ago. (In fact it might be *worse* than nothing because it might lead someone to believe your system is secure.) If you can, change to AES.

Comment: Well, anyway thanks for your hint. I'll talk about that with my supervisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved my Problem.

```
String strAsymmetricAlgName = SymmetricAlgorithmNames.DesEcbPkcs7;
SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider objAlgProv = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(strAsymmetricAlgName);

CryptographicKey keyPair = objAlgProv.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary("key", BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8));
IBuffer str = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(encodedDataAsBytes);
IBuffer buf = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(keyPair, str, null);
byte[] arr = buf.ToArray();
string returnValue = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(arr, 0, arr.Length);
```

Comment: This worked for me when looking for a solution to port code for use in Windows Phone 8.1 (RT). Required as we have a few million deployed cards using DES and TDES. I used Bouncy Castle for WP8.0 SL, but have now broken this dependency. Many thanks.

Comment: @user925327 - were you able to encrypt data using tripleDES ?